# Issues Connecting to SQLExpress using Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, sql-server-express, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to create a connection inside Oracle SQL Developer to a SQLExpress database I have

Everything I have resides on the same machine so there isn't any network issues I should have to deal with

but everytime I follow the instructions and I try to connect I get the following message

"Failure - Unable to get information from SQL Server: localhost."

I can connect to the SQLExpress DB using the SQL Management Studio and through an ODBC connection.

I've installed the third party extensions and I've enabled the TCP protocol on the SQL Server Configuration manager as well as enabled the IP Addresses

I'm assuming that the SQLExpress Database is on port 1433 because I didn't change this when I installed but if someone can tell me how to double check that I would appreciate that info as well.

I setup the new connection with the following information

name: databasename
I'm using windows authentication so the username and password aren't filled in
host:localhost
port:1433/databasename;instance=SQLEXPRESS

*databasename - this is replaced with the actual DB name I've just changed the name here to protect the innocent

I've spent about a full day on this trying to get it connected and many google attempts where other ppl have had this issue but have gotten it solved through various methods that I've tried and it hasn't resolved my issue.

Any information would be much appreciated

Thank you in Advance,
AD

Answer (score 4):

So I finally figured this out...I didn't know the SQL Server Browser service also had to be started...once I started that everything connected just fine.

Hopefully this will help someone in the future cause I spend two and a half days on it

Comment: Just want to confirm that this was also my solution to my problem.  The Server Browser Service had to be started.